# Horizontal scroll in PageviewController issue

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a view controller with horizontal scroll view.
This controller is contained in UIPageViewController.
My problem is this:

when I swipe horizontally the pageviewcontroller's page doesn't change because the swipe event is captured by horizontal scroll view (even if there is nothing to swipe).

P.S the horizontal scroll has same size of view controller's view

Comment: why you taken more complex use UICollectionview --> scroll direction (Horizontal) --> paging enabled option instead of UIscrollview & UIPageviewcontroller.

Comment: do you do an example? I want to get this: 3 controllers then I can swipe (like instagram for go from home to direct or camera. My central controller is that with horizontal scroll)

Comment: What is your expected behaviour when both scroll and change page exist? Do you want it to scroll or change page? If you gonna choose one, why do you put both of them together? Or do you want it to change page only when it has already scrolled to the end?

Comment: I want to change page only when it has already scrolled to the end

Comment: its like when in instagram app, user uploads more one photo and there is the photos horizontal photo and the swipe controllers for go to direct or camera